How to interface with Github Copilot LLM programmatically
I am trying to build a small app to interface with Github copilot LLM server OR if anyone found a way to interface with the Copilot LLM programatically in any other way.
I know that Github Copilot do not expose any APIs, is that still true in 2024?
I am aware of (How to invoke Github Copilot programmatically?) but not sure how accurate this info still is in 2024?
tried the following link (How to invoke Github Copilot programmatically?) but not sure how relevant this info still is in 2024.
appreciate any help.
